# Error using Clang tool to parse a C++ standard header file

Tags: c++, clang

I am using clang tool to parse standard header file  located in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/string. But I get the following error.

```
In file included from ~/PrototypeWork/user/header.hpp:3:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/string:41:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.7/bits/postypes.h:41:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tr1/cwchar:42:14: error: no member named 'wcstof' in namespace 'std'
  using std::wcstof;
        ~~~~~^
/usr/include/c++/4.7/tr1/cwchar:45:14: error: no member named 'vfwscanf' in namespace 'std'
  using std::vfwscanf;
    ~~~~~^
```

The problem seemed to be that clang is reading string header as a C header instead of c++ header and so it could not parse "using" keyword.
So I went ahead an added the -TP command line options that says to treat all source files as C++ but that did not help.

I get the following warning after using -TP command line option

```
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-T P'
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Clang command line options: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id5

Code

My main function has these:

```
    int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> cmdLine = boost::assign::list_of
                        ("-TP")
                        ("-I/usr/include")
                        ("-I/usr/include/c++/4.7/tr1/");
    clang::tooling::FixedCompilationDatabase db(".",cmdLine); 

// Provide clang with the header file that needs to be parsed

// Run the clang tool .
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you could reveal your source code

Comment: I do not have much code. I have a main function where I set up the FixedCompilationDatabases and command line options this way: std::vector<std::string> cmdLine = boost::assign::list_of
     ("-TP")
     ("-I/usr/include")
     ("-I/usr/include/c++/4.7/tr1/");
  clang::tooling::FixedCompilationDatabase db(".",cmdLine); After this I run the clang tool providing it the string header file to parse.

Comment: i doubt the problem is with clang. this means that you are doing something wrong with your code

Comment: Trying to compile gcc standard C++ library with clang is maybe not a good idea (because of some low-level stuff). Why do you need it in the first place ?

Comment: I am simply trying to create clang based tool to parse native header files.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this is a "Thank you, Captain Obvious" answer, but: is it possible that the code being parsed is simply failing to `#include <cwchar>`? `clang` is a bit more stringent by default than `gcc`, so you'll see an error like this if you've failed to include the header that declares the function.

Comment: It may be even more obvious: the header file H that OP is parsing, may simply *assume* that "#include <cwchar>" was processed before H was included.  Wouldn't be the first time a header file didn't have its full set of dependences.